Static Files not loading Django + Azure Web App
https://github.com/EPICS-HDR/New-Code-Layout
Thats the repo
I have tried everything on the internet. (New to web development, need help)
STATIC_URL = 'static/' STATICFILES_DIRS = [ BASE_DIR / 'services' /'static', ] STATIC_ROOT = os.path. join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage"
in urls.py:
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
standingrock.azurewebsites.net

I tried your code, made below changes, and was able to render static files without any issues.
Ensure your wsgi.py correctly sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to 'config.settings' and ensure your project structure is consistent. Make sure your packages are up to date.
Settings.py:
import os
from pathlib import Path
from .info import *
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
EMAIL_USE_TLS = EMAIL_USE_TLS
EMAIL_HOST = EMAIL_HOST
EMAIL_HOST_USER = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
EMAIL_PORT = EMAIL_PORT
ADMINS = (
    ('Vansh Thakkar', 'thakkar9@purdue.edu'),
)
SECRET_KEY = 'secretkey'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'services' / 'static',
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'services',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic'
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],  
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = ('whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage')

you need to include {% load static %} at the top of the file, before any references to static files.
views.py:
from services import views
from plotly.offline import plot 
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter 
import os
from datetime import datetime
import json
from .backend.database.sqlclasses import dictpull, moving_average
from .backend.graphgeneration.createCustom import customGraph, makeTable
from django.template.defaulttags import csrf_token
from config import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def favorites(request):
    saved_links = request.session.get('saved_links', [])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        link = request.POST.get('link')
        saved_links.append(link)
        request.session['saved_links'] = saved_links
        return redirect('favorites')
    return render(request, 'HTML/favorites.html', {'saved_links': saved_links})
    saved_links = Link.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'favorites.html', {'saved_links': saved_links})
def register(request):
    return render(request, "HTML/register.html")    
def vansh(request):
    return render(request, "HTML/vanshtest.html")
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']    
        if User.objects.filter(username=username):
            messages.error(request, "Username already exist! Please try some other username.")
            return redirect('home')        
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, "Email Already Registered!!")
            return redirect('home')
        if len(username)>20:
            messages.error(request, "Username must be under 20 charcters!!")
            return redirect('home')       
        if pass1 != pass2:
            messages.error(request, "Passwords didn't matched!!")
            return redirect('home')     
        if not username.isalnum():
            messages.error(request, "Username must be Alpha-Numeric!!")
            return redirect('home')        
        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.save()
        messages.success(request, "Your account has been succefully created. We have sent you a confirmation email, please confirm your email in order to activate your account")
        subject = "Welcome to HDR - Django Login!"
        message = "Hello" + myuser.first_name + "!! \n" + "Welcome to HDR!! \n Thank you for visiting our website \n We habe also sent you a confirmation email, please comfirm email adress in order to activate your account. \n\n Thanking you \n HDR TEAM"
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list = [myuser.email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_list, fail_silently = True)
        return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, "HTML/signup.html")
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']       
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=pass1)      
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            fname = user.first_name       
            return render(request, "HTML/register.html",{"fname":fname})
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Bad Credentials!!")
            return redirect('home') 
    return render(request, "HTML/signin.html")
def signout(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "Logged Out Successfully")
    return redirect('/register')
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'HTML/about.html')
def forecast(request):
    return render(request, 'HTML/forecast.html')
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'HTML/homepage.html')
def maptabs(request):
    return render(request, 'HTML/maptabs.html')   
def tabs(request):
    return render(request, 'graphing/tabs.html')
def tabstest(request):
    return render(request, 'graphing/tabstest.html')
def test(request):
    return render(request, 'graphing/test.html')
def customgauge(request):
    return render(request, 'graphing/customgauge.html')
def customdam(request):
    return render(request, 'graphing/customdam.html')
def custommesonet(request):
    return render(request, 'graphing/custommesonet.html')
def index(request):   
    return render(request, 'HTML/index.html')
def customgaugegraph(request):
    locationlist = request.POST.getlist('location')
    length = len(locationlist)
    data2see = request.POST['data2see']
    start_date = request.POST['start-date']
    end_date = request.POST['end-date']
    datalist = []
    sites = []
    index = 0
    while index < length:
        locations = locationlist[index]
        locations = locations.split()
        if locations[0] == "Little":
            locations[0] = "Little Eagle"
        sites.append(locations[0])
        times, data = dictpull(locations[0], data2see, start_date, end_date)
        m = moving_average()
        m_t, m_d = m.one_day_ma(times,data)
        datalist.append(data)
        index += 1    
   plot = customGraph(times, sites, datalist, data2see, 0)
    table = makeTable(datalist, 0)
    return render(request, "HTML/graphdisplay.html", context={'plot': plot, 'table': table})
def customdamgraph(request):
    locationlist = request.POST.getlist('dam')
    length = len(locationlist)
    data2see = request.POST['data2see']
    if "_" in data2see:
        data2see = data2see.split("_")
        data2see = data2see[0] + " " + data2see[1]
    start_date = request.POST['start-date']
    end_date = request.POST['end-date']
    folder_path = "./map/static/customdata/"
    datalist = []
    sites = []
    index = 0
    while index < length:
        sites.append(locationlist[index])
        times, data = dictpull(locationlist[index], data2see, start_date, end_date)
        datalist.append(data)
        index += 1      
    plot = customGraph(times, sites, datalist, data2see, 0)
    table = makeTable(datalist, 0)
    return render(request, 'HTML/graphdisplay.html', context={'plot': plot, 'table': table})
def custommesonetgraph(request):
    locationlist = request.POST.getlist('mesonet')
    length = len(locationlist)
    data2see = request.POST['data2see']
    if "_" in data2see:
        data2see = data2see.split("_")
        data2see = data2see[0] + " " + data2see[1]
    start_date = request.POST['start-date']
    end_date = request.POST['end-date']
    datalist = []
    sites = []
    index = 0
    while index < length:
        sites.append(locationlist[index])
        times, data = dictpull(locationlist[index], data2see, start_date, end_date)
        datalist.append(data)
        index += 1      
    plot = customGraph(times, sites, datalist, data2see, 0)
    table = makeTable(datalist, 0)
    return render(request, 'HTML/graphdisplay.html', context={'plot': plot, 'table': table})

urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from services.views import index, customgauge, customgaugegraph, customdam, customdamgraph, test, custommesonet, custommesonetgraph, tabs, tabstest, maptabs, homepage, forecast, about, register, signup, signin, signout, vansh
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from services import views  # Import the views module containing your view functions
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('customgaugegraph/', customgaugegraph),
    path('customdamgraph/', customdamgraph),
    path('customdam/', customdam),
    path('custommesonetgraph/', custommesonetgraph),
    path('map/', index),
    path('homep/', test),
    path('maptabs/', maptabs),
    path('home/', homepage),
    path('forecast/', forecast),
    path('about/', about),
    path('register/', register),
    path('signup/', signup, name='signup'), 
    path('signin/', signin, name='signin'), 
    path('signout/', signout, name='signout'), 
    path('favorites/', views.favorites, name='favorites'),
    path('vansh/', vansh)
]
urlpatterns += [
    path('', homepage), 
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

Run the below commands to collect static files to production
python manage.py collecstatic
python manage.py migrate

Make sure you change DEBUG =False in settings.py before deploying web app to Azure app service
local output:


Here's the output after deployment:

